# $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x^2-2x\cos(\theta)+1}\mathrm dx=\frac{\pi-\theta}{2\sin(\theta)}$

Tags: calculus

My question is  to prove this integral equality :

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x^2-2x\cos(\theta)+1}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{\pi-\theta}{2\sin(\theta)}$

where $\;0<\theta<\dfrac{\pi}{2}\,.$

I have tried to use partial fraction decompostion by complex numbers on,

$\dfrac{1}{x^2-2x\cos(\theta)+1}=\dfrac{1}{(x-e^{i\theta})(x-e^{-i\theta})}$

but how I can separate it ?

Please, help me with this question.

Comment: Try to treat $\cos(\theta)$ as a constant here

Comment: $\frac{1}{(x+e^{i\theta})(x+e^{-i\theta})}=(\frac{1}{x+e^{-i\theta}}-\frac{1}{x+e^{i\theta}})\frac1{e^{i\theta}-e^{-i\theta}}=(\frac{1}{x+e^{i\theta}}-\frac{1}{x+e^{-i\theta}})\frac i{2\sin\theta}$

Comment: Another possibility ... match the Fourier series of the two sides.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 4):

Express the denominator like this:
$$
x^2 + 2x\cos\theta +1 = x^2 + 2x\cos\theta + \cos^2\theta + \sin^2\theta = (x+\cos\theta)^2 + \sin^2 \theta
$$
and introduce the new variable
$$
z = x+\cos\theta\;,\qquad dz = dx
$$
Then your integral will become simply
$$
\int_{z=\cos\theta}^{z=1+\cos\theta}\frac{dz}{z^2+\sin^2\theta} = 
\frac{1}{\sin\theta} \int_{\cos\theta}^{1+\cos\theta} \frac{dz/\sin\theta}{1+(z/\sin\theta)^2}\;.
$$
At this point, you can switch to the new variable
$$
y = \frac{z}{\sin\theta}\;,\quad dy = \frac{dz}{\sin\theta}
$$
and recall that
$$
\int\frac{dy}{1+y^2} = \tan^{-1} y\;\,.
$$

Answer (score 2):

The fraction can be separated as:

$$
\frac1{x^2-2x\cos\theta+1}=\dfrac{1}{(x-e^{i\theta})(x-e^{-i\theta})}=
\frac1{2i\sin\theta}\left[\frac1{x-e^{i\theta}}-\frac1{x-e^{-i\theta}}\right].
$$

So:
$$
\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^2-2x\cos\theta+1}=
\frac1{2i\sin\theta}\left[\log\frac{x-e^{+i\theta}}{x-e^{-i\theta}}\right]_0^1
=\frac1{2i\sin\theta}\left[\log\left(-e^{i\theta}\right)-\log\left(e^{2i\theta}\right)\right]\\
=\frac1{2i\sin\theta}[i(\pi+\theta)-i(2\theta)]=\frac{\pi-\theta}{2\sin\theta}.
$$

In fact this expression is valid in a wider range $0<\theta<\pi$.